API not starting in IIS After Deployment: Missing .NET Hosting Components?
We deployed an ASP.NET Core 8 Web API to IIS. The API is not a self-contained deployment. The application pool was created and assigned to the application folder with Read and Read & Execute permissions, and the pool is started. The application folder also has a web.config file.
However, when we attempt to access the API through the client-side application, we never receive a response. It appears the application isn't starting, and IIS doesn't log any access to the API, though requests to the client-side code are logged successfully. The Event Viewer shows no errors or useful information.
When we manually run the application from the command line using dotnet .\<applicationName>.dll, it starts without any errors and produces logs as expected. Checking the HTTPErr logs shows requests to the API routes, but these requests are marked as canceled.
On our local and development environments, the application runs correctly. These environments have the following components installed:

Microsoft .NET 8.0.8 Windows Server Hosting
Microsoft .NET 8.0.8 Runtime (x86)
Microsoft .NET 8.0.8 Runtime (x64)
Microsoft ASP.NET Core 8.0.8 Shared Framework (x86)
[On the development server]: Microsoft ASP.NET Core 8.0.8 Shared Framework (x64)

However, on the production server (where the API fails to start), only the following component is installed:

Microsoft .NET 8.0.8 Windows Server Hosting

Could the issue be that the full .NET Hosting Bundle, including the necessary runtimes and ASP.NET Core shared frameworks, wasn't properly installed on the production server? If so, what are the necessary steps to resolve this?


You might enable IIS Failed Request Tracing to learn more about those requests without proper responses. 2) The missing .NET 8 runtime can be a significant issue, since your binaries were published not in self-contained mode. You might manually download the ASP.NET Core 8 runtime installers from https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/8.0 and install on this machine. That might resolve the issue.


@LexLi Thank you for your response.  The failed request logging is potentially a good suggestion.  I wonder if that would work though because doesn't failed request logging necessitate HTTP response codes?  Using Dev Tools, I see the request as pending, but never get a response.  We plan on uninstalling/reinstalling the hosting bundle to see if all of the components are installed.  I would like to have done that today, but we have to wait until HBSS is placed into logging mode.

You can use 200-999 when creating FRT rules, to catch all responses.

Did you perform an iisreset or reboot the machine after installing the .NET hosting bundle?

@mason That is a good question.  I sent an email to the server administrator to check to see if the server has been rebooted since that install.

You should also be able to do dotnet run on the prod box itself. This technique might give you more insights.

You can go to the .NET 8 download page and download the ASP.NET Core Runtime & Hosting Bundle. after installation, verify that both the ASP.NET Core Shared Framework and .NET Runtime for x64 and x86 are installed.
dotnet --list-runtimes

Once the installation is complete, restart IIS and try again.

Thanks for the response.  We ran the command and have the following results:
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 8.0.8 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 8.0.8 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]  However, I don't know if the server was rebooted or whether IIS was restarted at any point after the server admin installed the hosting bundle.  Additionally, when we checked the software installed the components mentioned in my original post were not present, so it appears the installation was probably not complete.

You can restart IIS by running this command: iisreset, try accessing your API again from the client-side application.

I marked yours as the answer.  We ended up just going ahead and rebooting the server.  This resolved the issue I was having.  The interesting thing is that running the command you provided shows the components as installed, but even after the reboot, they don't show in the installed software under "Add or Remove Programs."  Weird.  Other than a few database issues, I needed to take care of, everything appears to be running as expected.  Thanks for your help.
